# Streamlit Hosting

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, self-hosting, streamlit

I have made "streamlit dashboard app" and I need to deploy it on the pvt linux server of my team. I understand running "streamlit run app.py" - gives me the url and everyone within the startup-company with access to server is able to access it with that url and port 8501.

I used "nohup" cmd and make sure the process isnt killed but I am not sure if this is the right way?

I need to host this just like any other webapp port-number 8501 not visible on the url-bar.

I gave extensive searches but most of the contents are just about hosting it on heroku and streamlit hosting.

Sorry If am being naive about web dev and hosting but thats the reason I opted stremalit  even if I get direction I can find my way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is regarding deploying the streamlit app which is already placed in the server . Need to know how to deploy with a proper URL. So I am not sure code will be of any use here

Comment: Have you looked [into this page](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-deployment-guide-wiki/5099) in the community? Down below under "Webservers"?

Answer (score 3):

Hosting instructions are available at https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-deployment-guide-wiki/5099

There's more than a couple of links in there.
The one that seems most relevant to your need
is Standalone executable --> nginx -->
https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-docker-nginx-ssl-https/2195/5

That will let nginx worry about unruly internet clients,
password authentication, IP whitelists,
https certificates and the like,
proxying requests along to your port 8501.

Alternatively, note that `$ streamlit run --help`
comments on `--server.port INTEGER`.
You can also adjust this by setting
the environment variable `STREAMLIT_SERVER_PORT`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to modify the URL to localhost, it can be done by changing the streamlit configuration. Streamlit provides four different ways to set configuration options. Please refer: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/configuration

Below are two of the four methods which you can use to configure your streamlit app.

**Method 1:**
Using config.toml file. Place this file in a folder named .streamlit, which should in the same folder as the .py file you are trying to run.

**Folder structure:**

```
ParentFolder
  |__ main.py (# your python script )
  |__ .streamlit
    |__ config.toml
```

**Config File**

```
[server]
port = 7777
baseUrlPath = "/url_path/"

[browser]
serverAddress = "0.0.0.0"
```

**Method 2:** Adding the config parameters in the command line.

streamlit run main.py --server.port 7777 --server.baseUrlPath /url_path/ --server.serverAddress = '0.0.0.0'

The above config will run your app on the URL: http://localhost:7777/url_path/

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late but this issue bothered me for a while as well. My best shot so far is to use redir to redirect incoming traffic from port 80 to port 8105 :

```
sudo apt-get install redir
sudo redir --laddr=0.0.0.0 --lport=80 --caddr=0.0.0.0 --cport=8501
```

Then open port 80 and voila...